# make custom create-project with composer

Tags: composer-php

I would like to clone the *symfony-standard-edition create project* call but with some custom requirements.
So i dont need Swiftmailer or Doctrine ORM but would like to have the PaginatorBundle.

I tried to copy and edit the composer.json from the standard-edition and did a:

```
composer.phar install
```

but that did just install the vendor dir and not the rest like app folder, etc.

So how can i run:

```
composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject
```

with my edited composer.json?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just do `composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition myproject` to bootstrap the whole project, then remove the packages you don't need from composer.json and run update to delete them.

Otherwise you can also git clone the symfony/symfony-standard repository on github, and then start from there, running composer install once you tweaked the composer.json file.

Comment: alright, that is what i did in the end, just wondered if there was an alternative. thanx for the info.

Comment: we should also mention that its not just removing the packages from composer.json, you also have to clean the code created by symfony/framework-standard-edition: remove bundles from AppKernel, clean routes & config and any other occurences

Comment: Yes, because `create-project` is just a shortcut for a `git clone` and `composer install` unless I am mistaken.